# I want edit every single page in wordpress. Is possible?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Sorry if this question sounds stupid but im a noob with wordpress.

I am a javascript developer, and I want make a little game (or games) with wordpress. Opening main page there is a sliding puzzle. After complete, a button appears and clicking there you pass to another page. This is basically the same to all pages.

But I can't find were i put my javascript or HTML code. I create the pages but I can't edit them the way I want, everytime i try to do it i only can edit like word. I cant create, change or edit divs attibutes or tags. To be honest the only thing i can edit is CSS in stylesheet, but is too limited.

I have done the search, try found a solutions or ways to done it but when i look to tutorials is all diferent from what i see.

to give you an ideia I want to do a mix of this:
-> http://www.rustylake.com/room-escape-games/cube-escape-case-23.html 
and this 
-> https://ebonyriddle.com/

but i don't know how to edit page to page.
can you help me?

Thanks for everything

PS: I know I can do it without Wordpress, but I want use it anyway to learn more about the CMS (because of work) maintain website structure and later learn how to do my own templates or plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, yes it is possible (and easy, relatively speaking) to add custom code to every page / post of a Wordpress site.

More generally, you’re talking about creating a custom Wordpress theme, which you can find out more about here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

and here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/ (Good suggestion from [@ItsGeorge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827642/itsgeorge))

Regarding adding custom JavaScript to a theme, your files will need to be enqueued as per [these instructions](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#enqueuing-scripts-and-styles).

Outlining the steps involved in Wordpress theme development would go beyond the scope of your question, but there are plenty of resources online and answers to Wordpress specific questions on [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). You will need to familiarise yourself with [php](http://php.net) as well as JavaScript, to take full control of Wordpress.

I would say that developing a game feels like an odd fit... If learning Wordpress is your objective, a blog or personal website might be a better place to start, then you could move onto a game once you are familiar with the concepts involved, e.g. [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), which plays a huge part in how Wordpress works

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
Knowing is possible do what i want give some hope (I starting climb the walls).

I will study the links you gave me, and try do the work. 

Thanks for orientations is precise what i need. :)

Comment: In addition to the theme development docs in the codex, also check out the guide https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

The primary focus of WordPress is to put HTML code and JS out of the user. You might manage your extra JavaScript files with your theme customization. If you want to get more control about how your pages are rendering, you should use action hooks and filters. The simplest way for you is to override each page template like this
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-page

The preferable resource to ask Wordpress related questions is https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip that resource will be useful i didn't know it yet :)

Like Matt your answer will be useful as the tips he gave it to me  :) I really apreciate the help :)

I know the WordPress have objective to be simple but i want be advanced user, develop on it like the "normal way". Transform it, and change it.

I will study all the things you 2 give me. Thanks for help :)